# Error in iteration while comparing one file to another by character

Tags: c++, function, compare, increment

I am experiencing some difficulties while trying to compare one file to another character by character. Below I have the function in question. The goal of this function is to compare each character then calculated the efficiency of the comparison. I looked at a similar thread, yet after my program has run it stops incrementing after the 38th characters. I have checked each character and they are the same so I do not understand why this is occurring. And suggestions?

```
float compareFiles(string originalMessage, string decodedMessage)
{
    int totalChar = 0;
    int sameChar = 0;
    int diffChar = 0;

    cout << originalMessage << endl; //original message below
    /* no one would have believed in the last years of the nineteenth century that this world was being watched keenly and closely by intelligences greater than mans and yet as mortal as his own that as men busied themselves about their various concerns they were scrutinised and studied perhaps almost as narrowly as a man with a microscope might scrutinise the transient creatures that swarm and multiply in a drop of water with infinite complacency men went to and fro over this globe about their little affairs serene in their assurance of their empire over matter it is possible that the infusoria under the microscope do the same no one gave a thought to the older worlds of space as sources of human danger or thought of them only to dismiss the idea of life upon them as impossible or improbable it is curious to recall some of the mental habits of those departed days at most terrestrial men fancied there might be other men upon mars perhaps inferior to themselves and ready to welcome a missionary enterprise yet across the gulf of space minds that are to our minds as ours are to those of the beasts that perish intellects vast and cool and unsympathetic regarded this earth with envious eyes and slowly and surely drew their plans against us and early in the twentieth century came the great disillusionment the planet mars i scarcely need remind the reader revolves about the sun at a mean distance of 140000000 miles and the light and heat it receives from the sun is barely half of that received by this world it must be if the nebular hypothesis has any truth older than our world and long before this earth ceased to be molten life upon its surface must have begun its course the fact that it is scarcely one seventh of the volume of the earth must have accelerated its cooling to the temperature at which life could begin it has air and water and all that is necessary for the support of animated existence yet so vain is man and so blinded by his vanity that no writer up to the very end of the nineteenth century expressed any idea that intelligent life might have developed there far or indeed at all beyond its earthly level nor was it generally understood that since mars is older than our earth with scarcely a quarter of the superficial area and remoter from the sun it necessarily follows that it is not only more distant from times beginning but nearer its end */

    cout << decodedMessage << endl; //decoded message below
    /* no one would have believed in the last years of the nineteenth century that this world was being watched keenly and closely by intelligences greater than mans and yet as mortal as his own that as men busied themselves about their various concerns they were scrutinised and studied perhaps almost as narrowly as a man with a microscope might scrutinise the transient creatures that swarm and multiply in a drop of water with infinite complacency men went to and fro over this globe about their little affairs serene in their assurance of their empire over matter it is possible that the infusoria under the microscope do the same no one gave a thought to the older worlds of space as sources of human danger or thought of them only to dismiss the idea of life upon them as impossible or improbable it is curious to recall some of the mental habits of those departed days at most terrestrial men fancied there might be other men upon mars perhaps inferior to themselves and ready to welcome a missionary enterprise yet across the gulf of space minds that are to our minds as ours are to those of the beasts that perish intellects vast and cool and unsympathetic regarded this earth with envious eyes and slowly and surely drew their plans against us and early in the twentieth century came the great disillusionment the planet mars i scarcely need remind the reader revolves about the sun at a mean distance of 140000000 miles and the light and heat it receives from the sun is barely half of that received by this world it must be if the nebular hypothesis has any truth older than our world and long before this earth ceased to be molten life upon its surface must have begun its course the fact that it is scarcely one seventh of the volume of the earth must have accelerated its cooling to the temperature at which life could begin it has air and water and all that is necessary for the support of animated existence yet so vain is man and so blinded by his vanity that no writer up to the very end of the nineteenth century expressed any idea that intelligent life might have developed there far or indeed at all beyond its earthly level nor was it generally understood that since mars is older than our earth with scarcely a quarter of the superficial area and remoter from the sun it necessarily follows that it is not only more distant from times beginning but nearer its end */

    for(int q = 0; q <= originalMessage.length(); q++)
    {
            if(decodedMessage[q] == originalMessage[q])
            {
                    sameChar++;
            }
            else
            {
                    diffChar++;
            }
            totalChar++;
    }

    return ((float(sameChar)/float(totalChar))*100.00);
}
```

Comment: This program solves a Caesar cipher. these two blocks of nonsense text are just to original files true meaning and my decoded version of the text. Sorry about that, I thought I should include it. @Ron

Comment: `q < originalMessage.length();` otherwise you will be out of range

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to find how similiar are those 2 strings I would suggest this simple solution:

```
float compareFiles(const std::string& original, const std::string& decoded) {
    size_t length = original.size();
    size_t errorCount = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        if (original[i] != decode[i])
            ++errorCount;

    return 1.0f - float(errorCount)/float(lenght);
}
```

Also if those 2 messages are real files that you read from disk I would suggest to solve this using streams, since that's the format it is initially read into and not convert it to strings at all.

Comment: It is a Caesar cipher, both messages should be equal in length

Comment: Well should doesn't mean they will be every time. Better safe then sorry.

Comment: They cannot be different length, because of the way the cipher works, as it replaces chars with different chars so it is pretty much guaranteed the messages will be the same length.

Comment: I've made an edit to not check string sizes. Does this solution work for you?

Comment: In my program, i remove all punctuation and capitalization from both. The goal of this function, in particular, is to calculate the efficiency of my letter conversion. I don't really know how to use what was used in this suggested answer. I don't know properties of size_t or 1.0f

Comment: `size_t` is just an type alias for unsigned integer and i've used it because it more clearly describes what that number is (`size_t length` is a size of `original`). `1.0f` is just a floating point number which I use because to get the similarity percentage you just do 1 - error.